# Can't access Html form elements in php file on submit getting error unspecified index?

Tags: php, html

This is the file `upload.php`. When I try to submit the HTML form and get the value of `stateCode` it throws an unspecified index error, please see attached screenshot

```
        <html>
        <body>
        <?php
        $target_dir = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."/files/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]
        ["name"]);
        $dst = $target_file;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        echo $_POST['stateCode'] ;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;

        }
       // Check file size
       if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
           echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
       }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "xls" && $imageFileType != "xlsx" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only Excel files are allowed.";

        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The following is `welcome.html` whenever I try to submit this form I get the below error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<style>
#form {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
label {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
    height: 35px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right:15px;
    float:left;
}
iframe {
    height:35px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top:14px;
  }
 button{
 margin-top: 18px;
 }
</style>
<script>


 var dvalues='';

function myFunction(){
  var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var b =innerDoc.body;
 var c = b.childNodes;
 var dvalues = b.childNodes[0].value;
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML =dvalues;
 }
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=dvalues;
};

</script>
<body>


<div id = "form">
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="States" name ="states">States:</label>
    <iframe id ="frame" name="myPHPScript" src="myScript.php" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <p  id = "placeholder" name="stateCode"></p>    

    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" /><input type="submit" name="action"onclick="myFunction()"/>

 </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your stateCode is in a `p` tag, not an `input` tag.

Comment: var_dump $_POST and see what it contains, ^^^yeah that will cause it

Comment: @TrevorD thanks for replaying , tried var_dump $_POST and  it throws error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE)"

Comment: @aynber tried with input tag too ,  not working !

Comment: you have to have parentheses around `$_POST`. So `vardump($_POST);`

Comment: @aynber is correct, you need to have an `<input>` tag. `<p>` won't send anything during a `POST`.

Comment: @TrevorD got the output array(1) { ["action"]=> string(6) "Submit"

Comment: You have your answer, the very first comment.  the var_dump will just show it isn't there because `p` tags aren't submitted with a form.

Comment: @aynber sure , I tried input too got output array(2) { ["stateCode"]=> string(0) "" ["action"]=> string(6) "Submit" }

Comment: You should now be able to get `$_POST['stateCode']` in your PHP.

Comment: @a.s. Did you put a value into that input?

Comment: Fixed grammar and formatting. Low quality is due to lack of understanding more than the question itself. (i.e. using `<p>` tags in `<form>` instead of `<input>` O_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<style>
#form {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
label {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #333;
    height: 35px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right:15px;
    float:left;
}
iframe {
    height:35px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top:14px;
  }
 button{
 margin-top: 18px;
 }
</style>
<script>


 var dvalues='';

function myFunction(){
  var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var b =innerDoc.body;
 var c = b.childNodes;
 var dvalues = b.childNodes[0].value;
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML =dvalues;
 }
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=dvalues;
};

</script>
<body>


<div id = "form">
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="States" name ="states">States:</label>
    <iframe id ="frame" name="myPHPScript" src="myScript.php" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <p id = "placeholder"></p>
    <input type="text"   name="stateCode" />   


    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" /><input type="submit" name="action"onclick="myFunction()"/>

 </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Fixed p into input type text.  Not sure what you actually intended the type to be but that should get you running.

Comment: I am beginner to php, I am supposed to get the value which is coming from dropdown  and set it to this input element and parse  it into excel file's column, still it's not working not sure what is wrong now.